# Java : Removing zeros after decimal point in BigDecimal

Tags: java

I have a program like this ,

```
BigDecimal bd = new BigDecimal(23.086);
BigDecimal bd1= new BigDecimal(0.000);

bd = bd.setScale(2, RoundingMode.HALF_UP).stripTrailingZeros();
bd1 = bd1.setScale(2, RoundingMode.HALF_UP).stripTrailingZeros();

System.out.println("bd value::"+ bd);
System.out.println("bd1 value::"+ bd1);
```

I get the following output: `23.09` for `bd` and 0.00 for `bd1`, but I want `bd1` as `0` not as `0.00`. Am I applying the methods correctly?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
BigDecimal bd  = new BigDecimal(23.086); 
BigDecimal bd1 = new BigDecimal(0.000);

bd  = bd.setScale(2, RoundingMode.HALF_UP).stripTrailingZeros(); 
bd1 = bd1.setScale(2, RoundingMode.HALF_UP).stripTrailingZeros();

System.out.println("bd value::"+ bd); System.out.println("bd1 value::"+ bd1);
System.out.println("new way:" + bd1.intValueExact());
```

//OUTPUT
bd value::23.09

bd1 value::0.00

new way:0

Comment: But how do you KNOW if you should call intValueExact? I want output 1.1 if thats correct, and 1 if thats correct

Comment: Erm you call that function when you want BigDecimal to an INTEGER. But need to catch for ArithmeticException.

If you want to covert to double, you need to find a build in function to covert to bigdecmical to double
 
https://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/math/bigdecimal_intvalueexact.htm

Comment: I agree, but the question wasn't how to convert BigDecimal to int, the question was how to format output without any trailing zeros. Which are different things to me.

Comment: I see, I haven't come across format output functions before. Can't answer your question. sorry

Comment: wrong answer, try BigDecimal(200.0000), you get 2E+2, not the desired 200

Answer (score 24):

try this

```
import java.math.BigDecimal;
import java.text.DecimalFormat;

public class calculator{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        BigDecimal bd = new BigDecimal(23.086);
        BigDecimal bd1= new BigDecimal(0.000);    
        DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("0.##");    
        System.out.println("bd value::"+ df.format(bd));
        System.out.println("bd1 value::"+ df.format(bd1));

    }

}
```

Comment: This will convert it to a String, you can wrap it in a "new BigDecimal(df.format(bd))" to create a BigDecimal again.

Answer (score 22):

Let's say you have BigDecimal with value `23000.00` and you want it to be `23000`. You can use method `stripTrailingZeros()`, but it will give you "wrong" result:

```
BigDecimal bd = new BigDecimal("23000.00");
bd.stripTrailingZeros() // Result is 2.3E+4
```

You can fix it by calling `.toPlainString()` and passing this to the BigDecimal constructor to let it handle correctly:

```
BigDecimal bd = new BigDecimal("23000.00");
new BigDecimal(bd.stripTrailingZeros().toPlainString()) // Result is 23000
```

Answer (score 15):

**Simple, clean, flexible, easy-2-understand and maintain code**

(*will work for `double` too*)

```
DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat();
df.setMaximumFractionDigits(2); //Sets the maximum number of digits after the decimal point
df.setMinimumFractionDigits(0); //Sets the minimum number of digits after the decimal point
df.setGroupingUsed(false); //If false thousands separator such ad 1,000 wont work so it will display 1000

String result = df.format(bd);
System.out.println(result);
```

Answer (score 6):

You can use [`printf()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/PrintStream.html#printf%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Object...%29) -- the `%f` specifier works for `BigDecimal`s too:

```
System.out.printf("bd1 value::%.0f%n", bd1);
```

```
bd1 value::0
```

Answer (score 4):

You can do this

```
System.out.println("bd value: " + ((bd.scale() == 0) ? bd.unscaledValue() : bd));
```

Answer (score 2):

This method below works better IMO

```
    bd1 = bd1.stripTrailingZeros();
    System.out.println(bd1.toPlainString());
```

Prints:

```
    0
```

If bd1 = 1.2300 , this will print

```
    1.23
```

Comment: How this is different than the @Gondy's answer?

Answer (score 0):

i create this method to fix my problem...

```
private BigDecimal removeZeros(BigDecimal bigDecimal){
            return new BigDecimal(bigDecimal.stripTrailingZeros().toPlainString());
        }
```

i don't like it, but do the job

Comment: How is this different than @Gondy's answer?

Answer (score 0):

IMO `.stripTrailingZeros()` is already the correct approach. If the goal is to only strip trailing zeroes after the decimal point, you can reset the scale back to 0 if it is below 0 after calling `.stripTrailingZeros()`:

```java
BigDecimal bd = new BigDecimal("100.00");           // bd ==> 100.00
bd = bd.stripTrailingZeros();                       // bd ==> 1E+2
if (bd.scale() < 0)
    bd = bd.setScale(0, RoundingMode.UNNECESSARY);  // bd ==> 100
```